# MySQL returning wrong record

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a query on my page and it is returning the wrong results.
Here is my code:

```
$timestamp = time();
$query = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE expire >= $timestamp AND home = 1 AND active = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        $$key = $value;
    }
}
```

The problem is, it is returning the SECOND record, and not the most recent ID.  But, strange part is, if I run this in the Query window of MySQL, it returns the correct record.

This is the data on the record it should return:
id: 53, videoid: abc123, expire:1335596400, home: 1, active:1

Anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: Have you tried ordering by the expire field instead?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with your computer's timezone?

Comment: It's because you're ordering by `DESC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1335596400` is `28 april`, so cleary is not the result from `time()`;
It seems that you are runnign the query with another timestamp in MySQL (or without timestamp at all)

Comment: Funny how you can look right past something when you've been staring at the monitor for so long...  Thanks for helping me see my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

use
$query = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE expire >= $timestamp AND home = 1 AND active = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1";

instead

$query = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE expire >= $timestamp AND home = 1 AND active = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";